# Why is $name field never !, even when empty?

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement

I have a basic sign up form, and when checking if a field is not set (if(!$name)) it always goes to 'else', even when the field is empty.
Does anyone know why?
(When i'm trying to check it in reverse (if($name)), it does show the error line. )
*var_dump($name) - always returns a string, never false. I'm guessing thats part of the problem?...

Thanks a lot!!

```
<?php
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

  if( !$name && preg_match("/^([\w]){2,50}$/", $name)){ 

    $error = ' * Please enter a valid name';

}
```

?>

```
 <form action="" method="post">

            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name">   <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
            <span class="error"><?= $error ?></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code does not match your question

Comment: How is $name supposed to match that regex if it is an empty string? It is impossible to satisfy both conditions. Did you mean to use `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @gla3dr that is exactly it and that's all that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you got wrong IF statement. You are checking if $name is false (it will be only if you send empty string) AND if it's length is between 2-50.

Consider two states:

```
<?php
$name = 'Login';
$a = !$name; // FALSE! You're variable is OK, but you neg it
$b = preg_match("/^([\w]){2,50}$/", $name); // TRUE! Between 2-50 letters

<?php
if($a && $b) { 
    die("Won't be visible, because $a and $b are not the same");
}
```

And second:

```
$name = '';
$a = !$name; // TRUE! You're variable is empty, but you neg it
$b = preg_match("/^([\w]){2,50}$/", $name); // FALSE! has 0 letters

if($a && $b) { 
    die("Won't be visible, because $a and $b are not the same");
}
```

So, you should use OR instead of AND or just forget about first statement (second is checking same thing!):

```
<?php
if(!preg_match("/^([\w]){2,50}$/", $name)){ 
    $error = ' * Please enter a valid name';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're getting that undefined variable notice because you're trying to echo something in your form that hasn't already been set/not empty and your PHP/HTML form are used in the same file.</strike>

Sidenote: `<?=` is short tag syntax for "echo".

So change:

```
<?= $error ?>
```

to and with a conditional statement:

```
<?php if(!empty($error)) { echo $error; } ?>
```

or:

```
<?php if(isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?>
```

Or use a ternary operator:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

or add an `else` to my suggestion above.

Plus, you also have a missing brace in your PHP (least, for what you posted) and that alone should have thrown you an unexpected end of file error.

**Edit:**

The reason that it is failing is the operator you're using, being `&&` (AND). Use `||` (OR), to check if either one failed the criteria and not both. You're checking if there's no name AND if there's enough valid characters.

```
if( !$name || preg_match("/^([\w]){2,50}$/", $name))
```

and that's all it was, a simple wrong choice of operator.

Btw, my edit wasn't based on the other answer given. I actually was busy testing this out when that was posted.

Their explanation is well-written/explained, however they're working too hard.

Changing `&&` to `||` in your code would have worked just fine.

Comment: I'm using the short tag because i wan't it to echo the error if there is one (otherwise it's an empty string) but the problem is, that the field is neve recognized as empty

Comment: @user3185970 use a ternary operator then, as I added in my answer in an edit. or add an "else".

Comment: thanks, i don't want to check $error though. I need to check $name.
I do get the error if i check it the other way around, because the regular expression detect a problem, but when checkinh !($name) it always goes to 'else'. never recognized as empty

Comment: @user3185970 you also have a missing brace

Comment: @user3185970 reload and see my edit. it's the operator you're using `&&` which should have been `||`. That's all it was.